# Log alamofire upload image request and response

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, alamofire

I know there is a lot about this issue but I can't find exactly the one related to uploading. I'm using [alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for my HTTP calls.
I'm trying to upload the image to Amazon S3 and getting an error, wanting to log request and response to see what exactly problem is.

All my requests are logging except Alamofire.upload. I added an extension to request and Aramofire.request is logging and now my problem is to log also Alamofire.upload.

As an example, I'm trying to log request and response for the following example.

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
    for (key, value) in params {
        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: key)
    }
    if image != nil {
        if let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.8) {
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
    }
   }, to: "amazon.s3.URL")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into SessionManager class I found out the way how to log upload request and response.
I override the upload function.

Here is my example

```
class AlamofireManager: SessionManager {

    override func upload(_ data: Data, with urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> UploadRequest {
        let request = super.upload(data, with: urlRequest)

        print("Request: \(request.debugDescription)")

        print("Response: \(request.response.data)")

        return request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this pod https://github.com/konkab/AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger and you can call it in `applicationDidLaunch..` it will log everything pretty nice.